# Como mandar datos a otro DataGridView, si en el primer DataGridView tengo un RowCount?

Tags: c#, sql-server

mi problema es el siguiente, estoy realizando un sistema de matricula para mi Colegio, y lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera: mi base de datos esta estructurada así:

```
create table ingreso
(RNE int primary key not null,
Apellido nvarchar(50),
Nombre nvarchar(50),
Procedencia nvarchar(50),
Encargado nvarchar(50),
Telefono int,
Edad int,
Instituto_Anterior nvarchar(100),
Promedio int)
```

esa es toda mi base de datos, en *visual studio* pues puse un `textbox` por cada campo, tambien un `datagridview`, un boton para ingresar datos, uno para eliminarlos, uno para ingresar un nuevo dato(que solo limpia los `textbox`), un boton de reporte(que crea un reporte con los datos del `datagridview`), y un boton de ordenar(que esta vinculado con un `textbox`, su principal objetivo es mostrar en el `datagridview` unicamente la cantidad de datos que se especifica en el `textbox`(que se le asigne el nombre de `txtfiltro`), ademas de ordenarlos por la columna `promedio`, mediante en el siguiente codigo:

```
private void btnordenar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SET ROWCOUNT " + txtfiltro.Text + " Select RNE, Nombres, Apellidos, Promedio from Ingreso order by Promedio desc;", sqlConnection);

            using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var datable = new DataTable();
                datable.Load(dr);
                this.dgvAlumnos.DataSource = datable;
                this.dgvAlumnos.Refresh();
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }
```

En el `Datagrid` unicamente muestro 4 datos, el `RNE`, `Nombre` y `Promedio`.

El Problema viene cuando me piden que los datos que quedan fuera del rango impuesto en el `txtfiltro`, se muestren en otro `datagridview`, quedando asi el primer `datagrid` como los estudiantes admitidos para la jornada matutina, y los demás para la jornada vespertina, la verdad no se como hacer esto.

este es mi codigo completo:

```
namespace Sistema_Matrícula
    {
    public partial class Ingreso_Datos : Form
    {
        public Ingreso_Datos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = Conexión.connection;

        private void llenargrid()
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select RNE, Apellidos, Nombres, Promedio from Ingreso", sqlConnection);


                using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var datable = new DataTable();
                    datable.Load(dr);
                    this.dgvAlumnos.DataSource = datable;
                    this.dgvAlumnos.Refresh();
                }
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
        }

        private void btnagregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Ingreso values (@RNE," +
                "@Apellidos," +
                "@Nombres," +
                "@Procedencia," +
                "@Encargado," +
                "@Telefono," +
                "@Edad," +
                "@Instituto_Anterior," +
                "@Promedio)", sqlConnection);

            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("RNE", txtRNE.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Apellidos", txtApellidos.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nombres", txtNombres.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Procedencia", txtProcedencia.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Encargado", txtEncargado.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Telefono", txtTelefono.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Edad", txtEdad.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Instituto_Anterior", txtColegio.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Promedio", txtPromedio.Text);

            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Guardado Exitosamente!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error de Guardado...", ex.Message);
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
            llenargrid();
        }

        private void btneliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvAlumnos.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Desea eliminar este registro?", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    var codigoSeleccionado = Convert.ToInt32(this.dgvAlumnos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Delete from Ingreso where RNE = @RNE", sqlConnection);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("RNE", codigoSeleccionado);


                    try
                    {
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlConnection.Close();
                        llenargrid();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        MessageBox.Show("No se pudo eliminar este Campo...", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                        throw;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private void btnordenar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SET ROWCOUNT " + txtfiltro.Text + " Select RNE, Nombres, Apellidos, Promedio from Ingreso order by Promedio desc;", sqlConnection);

                using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var datable = new DataTable();
                    datable.Load(dr);
                    this.dgvAlumnos.DataSource = datable;
                    this.dgvAlumnos.Refresh();
                }
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
        }

        private void Ingreso_Datos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            llenargrid();
        }





        private void btnnuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtRNE.Text = "";
            txtApellidos.Text = "";
            txtNombres.Text = "";
            txtEncargado.Text = "";
            txtTelefono.Text = "";
            txtProcedencia.Text = "";
            txtEdad.Text = "";
            txtPromedio.Text = "";
            txtColegio.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

voy bien? solo necesito que los datos que no entran en el rango del `ROWCOUNT` se muestren en otro `DataGridView`.

Gracias de Antemano!!!!!

Saludos desde Honduras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizá en lugar de hacerlo en la consulta, lo podrías hacer utilizando LINQ:

```
int i=0;

// Realizas la consulta completa
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(" Select RNE, Nombres, Apellidos, Promedio from Ingreso order by Promedio desc;", sqlConnection);

// Obtienes numero registros ingresados por el usuario
int numeroRegistros = Convert.ToInt32(txtfiltro.Text);

using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
   // Cargas datos al objeto
   var dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Load(dr);

   // Revisas que se hayan obtenido datos
   if(dt.Rows!= null && dt.Rows.Count>0)
   {
       // Obtienes los que el usuario quería
       var pedidosPorUsuario = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(numeroRegistros);

       // Obtienes los restantes
       var restantes = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>{
          i++;
          return i>numeroRegistros;
       });

       // Se convierte a DataTable y asignas a los datagridview
       this.dgvRequeridos.DataSource = pedidosPorUsuario.Count() > 0 ? pedidosPorUsuario.CopyToDataTable() : null;
       this.dgvRestantes.DataSource = restantes.Count() > 0 ? restantes .CopyToDataTable() : null;

   }
   else
   {
      this.dgvRequeridos.DataSource = null;
      this.dgvRestantes.DataSource = null;
   }

   this.dgvRequeridos.Refresh();
   this.dgvRestantes.Refresh();

}
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias!!!, solo una pregunta, tengo que usar alguna libreria adicional para que funcione?

Comment: System.Collections.Generic, System.Data, System.Linq. No olvides votar las respuestas (si ahorita no puedes por reputación puedes hacerlo cuando te lo permitan) así se fortalece la comunidad.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, de veras!!!

Comment: Hola de nuevo, me surgió un pequeño problema, en el primer datagrid me muestra los datos que yo quiero, pero en el segundo, me muestra todos los datos que hay dentro de la base, no solo los que sobran, como lo podré solucionar_

Comment: Revisa que la parte de restantes esté filtrando correctamente los que sobran.

Comment: En absoluto, en el Datagrid de restantes, me sigue mostrando todos los datos de la Base de datos.